# Microsoft Virtual Audio Device Driver Sample (MSVAD) only creates 44 bytes files

Tags: c++, windows, wdk

I'm currently digging into the MSVAD simple driver. Unfortunately, it doesn't work the way I'd like it to work. When a new program starts, it creates as STREAM_NN.WAV under C:\

Unfortunately, this file is only 44 bytes in size (containing only the header). I attached the debugger view and got this output:

```
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclic::NewStream]
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicMSVAD::ValidateFormat]
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclic::NewStream]
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicMSVAD::ValidateFormat]
MSVAD: CMiniportWaveCyclicMSVAD::ValidatePcm
MSVAD: [CSaveData::InitializeWorkItems]
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMSVAD::Init]
MSVAD: SaveData 845A754C
MSVAD: [CSaveData::SetDataFormat]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::Initialize]
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMSVAD::AllocateBuffer]
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMSVAD::SetFormat]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::SetDataFormat]
MSVAD: New Format: 44100
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMSVAD::SetNotificationFreq]
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMSVAD::SetState]
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMSVAD::SetState]
MSVAD: KSSTATE_PAUSE
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMSVAD::SetState]
MSVAD: KSSTATE_RUN
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=480]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1284]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=628]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1136]
//Truncated for convenience
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=776]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=988]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WriteData ulByteCount=1764]
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMSVAD::SetState]
MSVAD: KSSTATE_PAUSE
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMSVAD::SetState]
MSVAD: KSSTATE_STOP
MSVAD: [CSaveData::WaitAllWorkItems]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::SaveFrame]
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMSVAD::SetState]
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicStream::~CMiniportWaveCyclicStream]
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMS::~CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMS]
MSVAD: [CMiniportWaveCyclicStreamMSVAD::FreeBuffer]
MSVAD: [CSaveData::~CSaveData]
```

That looks pretty straight forward to me, e.g. all necessary functions got called. I'm wondering if there is a known bug in this example, or any caveats I have to take into account?

The OS is Windows 7 32bit in a virtual machine, normal audio playback works like a charm. The Simple driver is set as default playback device.

Comment: Do you know if `WriteData` is actually succeeding? Are you checking error returns?

Comment: Which DDK version are you using? DDK 8.1 MSVAD had some issues (at least I faced it). Try the MSVAD version available in WDK 7.1.

Comment: @CareyGregory, at least it looked like it would work - I need to dig deeper into that.

Comment: @Favonius, I'll try using the version from WDK 7.1, thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that since the DDK 8 in the method **CSaveData::InitializeWorkItems (savedata.cpp)** were added following lines:

```
if (m_pWorkItems)
{
    return ntStatus;
}
```

But **CSaveData::~CSaveData** is freeing only "work items", not the m_pWorkItems array. This leads to the use of the freed "work items" in future.

To solve this problem you need to replace the code in **savedata.cpp, CSaveData::InitializeWorkItems**:

```
if (m_pWorkItems)
{
    return ntStatus;
}

m_pWorkItems = (PSAVEWORKER_PARAM)
    ExAllocatePoolWithTag
    (
        NonPagedPool,
        sizeof(SAVEWORKER_PARAM) * MAX_WORKER_ITEM_COUNT,
        MSVAD_POOLTAG
    );
```

By this code:

```
if (!m_pWorkItems)
{
    m_pWorkItems = (PSAVEWORKER_PARAM)
        ExAllocatePoolWithTag
        (
            NonPagedPool,
            sizeof(SAVEWORKER_PARAM) * MAX_WORKER_ITEM_COUNT,
            MSVAD_POOLTAG
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your posting - I'm currently out of the office, but I'll try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Finally, back at the office - and a huge thank you, works like a charm. :)